# 開いている、開けてある、and other verb forms for "to be opened"

Tags: grammar

> ドアが開いている。
>
> ドアが開けてある。
>
> ドアが開いてある。
>
> ドアが開けたままになっている。
>
> ドアが開けたままだった。
>
> ドアが開けられている。

Could you please explain the subtle variations between these six sentences? Are all grammatically correct and natural-sounding? (of course, depending on context)

My current understanding is below; I would appreciate if you could confirm or deny them!

> ドアが開いている。The door is open.
>
> ドアが開けてある。The door is left open. The door is open and left that way by someone.
>
> ドアが開いてある。The door is in an opened state. (reason is unspecified, whether it was left open or whatnot)
>
> ドアが開けたままになっている。The door is LEFT open. (emphasis on left)
>
> ドアが開けたままだった。The door was left open. (past tense of the previous sentence)
>
> ドアが開けられている。The door is left open (generally; not referring to a specific occasion)

Comment: Can you clarify what verb you're asking about? 開く (particularly) and 開ける have multiple readings. Knowing which verb you are asking about helps rule out misunderstandings of transitivity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ドアが開いてある is ungrammatical. The other five are natural.

1. **ドアが開いている**: The door is open.
   <sub>(Implies nothing about why it's open or how it opened. Maybe it opened by itself, or maybe it was opened by the wind.)</sub>
2. **ドアが開けられている**: The door has been opened (by someone).
   <sub>(Unlike 1, you're at least sure that it was opened by someone.)</sub>
3. **ドアが開けてある**: Someone has opened the door (e.g., for me).
   <sub>(The door is open, and you're sure that someone has opened it in advance, for a reason)</sub>
4. **ドアが開いてある**: (makes no sense)
5. **ドアが開けたままだ = ドアが開けたままになっている**: The door is LEFT open.
   <sub>(You believe it should be closed.)</sub>
6. **ドアが開けたままだった = ドアが開けたままになっていた**: The door was LEFT open.
   <sub>(Past tense of 5.)</sub>